# Problem dealing with Probability Generating Functions

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Below is a problem I did. However, I did not come up with the answer in book.
I am hoping somebody can point out what I did wrong or that the book is wrong.

> Let $Y = aX + b$. Express the probability generating function of $Y$,
>   $G_Y(z)$ in terms of the probability generating function of $X$, $G_X(z)$.

Answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
G_Y(z) &=& E(z^Y) = E(z^{aX+b}) = E(z^b z^{aX}) = z^b E(z^{aX}) \\
G_X(x) &=& E(z^x) \\
G_X(ax) &=& E(z^{ax}) \\
G_Y(z) &=& z^b G_X(ax) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
However, the book gets:
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_Y(z) &=& z^a G_X(z^b) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The definition of $Y$ might be $Y=a+bX$, in which case indeed $G_Y(z)=z^aG_X(z^b)$. But if $Y=aX+b$, then $G_Y(z)=z^bG_X(z^a)$, period. (Your post was absolutely flooded with inconherent notations, I corrected a few, but stopped at $G_X(x)$, which is absurd but might reflect some misconception of yours.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why $$\operatorname{E}[z^{a X}] \ne G_X(ax)$$ is because $X$ is a random variable over which the expectation is taken.  The generating function cannot be a function of a realization of $X$.  Notice that when we write $$G_X(z) = \operatorname{E}[z^X],$$ the $X$ is random and the function on the LHS is a function of $z$.  So if you modify the RHS expectation to $$\operatorname{E}[z^{a X}],$$ this should now be a function of $a$ and $z$, not $a$ and $X$.  Since $$\operatorname{E}[z^{a X}] = \operatorname{E}[(z^a)^X],$$ the substitution $u = z^a$ clearly makes the RHS equal to $G_X(u) = G_X(z^a)$.

Answer (score 0):

I obtain
\begin{align}
G_Y(z) & = \mathbb{E}[z^{Y}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[z^{aX+b}] \\
&= z^{b} \mathbb{E}[(z^a)^X] \\
& = z^{b} G_{x}(z^a).
\end{align}